# XSLT - How to to check my element value is in a pre defined group of values?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am getting a department_code in my xml. Here I need to check if this value belongs to pre defined dept groups if so I need to display 'Yes' Else 'No'

if dept id is in (100,200,300,400,500 long list like 170 codes) then YES else I need to send as NO

How can I check this in XSLT ?

Thanks
Venk

Comment: This is in XSLT

Answer (score 1):

If you define a global variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="codes" select="('100', '200', '300')" />
```

Then you can write your test as this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (@department_code = $codes) then 'yes' else 'no'" />
```

(Here I am assuming `department_code` is an attribute in your XML, so you might need to adjust it if not).

See an example at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2De